# Adding backslash automatically for label value in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have label having value 'Mandatory/optional' but it automatically adds backslash like-
**'Mandatory\/Optional'** as label value.

```
[Display(Name = "Mandatory/Optional")]
public bool Mandatory { get; set; }
```

This is how I am setting value for the label.

I think browser is adding this extra slash. Please suggest solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use escape character for adding slash like `"\/"`

Comment: When I add '//' it adding two '\\'. like 'Mandatory\/\/Optional'

Comment: I did it using HTML code for front slash. It worked for me. Thanks everyone.